# Error checking attempt, how would I fix this?

Tags: c, struct, visual-studio-code, return-type

For a homework assignment I was tasked with adding error checks to code. I have two left: one I understand what I need to write an error check for, but cannot get it to work, the other I haven't found what to check for yet.

I've tried changing the return type of read_edge to allow use of return 0; to end the function when finding an error, but this resulted in g.edges receiving wrong types. I've also tried setting the error check just before main calls read_edge on a test 'edge' struct, but it had no effect on catching the error.

```
typedef int vertex;

typedef struct {
    vertex source;
    vertex target;
    float weight;
} edge;

typedef struct {
    int n;
    int m;
    vertex* vertices;
    edge* edges;
} graph;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
edge read_edge(FILE* file) {
    edge e;
        if (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f", &e.source, &e.target, &e.weight) != 3){
        printf("Error: Expected an Integer and/or Float\n");
        return 0;
    }
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %f", &e.source, &e.target, &e.weight);
    return e;
}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and this bit is the part of main that calls read_edge:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    graph g = create_graph(n, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        // missing error check 
        g.edges[i] = read_edge(file);
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", g.n, g.m);

    return 0;
}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Clearly this will get compilation errors because of me trying to return 0; in a return type of 'edge' but I'm not sure how to allow this to happen.

Comment: I see the second fscanf in read_edge isn't needed, meant to remove that before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the functions so that they return an `int`, and take a pointer to the struct to be filled in as a parameter.

Also, you shouldn't call `fscanf()` twice. The second call will try to read the next structure from the file, not reread what you read when you were testing the result.

```
int read_edge(FILE* file, edge *e) {
    if (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f", e->source, e->target, e->weight) != 3){
        printf("Error: Expected two integers and float\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

In the caller, instead of

```
e = read_edge(f);
```

you use something like

```
int success = read_edge(f, &e);
```

So the other function would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    int success = read_edge(file, &g.edges[i]);
    if (!success) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this still read the 'edges' into the graph g struct correctly? @Barmar

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use it with the `graph` structure.

Comment: Ahh I see. That makes much more sense. If the file reads in what it needs to though, what error check could I be looking for in the loop? Everything looks good at that point.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Testing the `success` variable is the error check.

Comment: My original error check was making sure fscanf in read_edge read in all three needed values. %d %d and %f. Which with your addition it does check for, supposedly my instructor left a comment in for loop under create_graph that an error check was needed there. I believe you just solved both error checks in answering the first though.